# AWS Cognito - Get user details like lastname, profile image

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-cognito

I am working on a flutter application, where user profile image, first name, last name are to be displayed in profile screen. I have referred to `amplify_auth_cognito` package, looks like there are no exposed APIs for getting user details.

Is there a way to achieve this?

PS: you could also suggest any iOS libraries, if you are aware.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advane.

Comment: If your profile image, first name, last name are stored on cognito you can get them by decoding the id token returned when you login. I'm not familiar with IOS but you can look up how to access the id token and then just decode it

Comment: @NinadGaikwad, thank you for your reply. Could you please explain what does decode mean here? Regarding token, how to I get it ?

Comment: So your Tokens are Base64-encoded JSON strings. You can decode them programatically. Just google "decode base64 string in android" and you'll find plenty of solutions. 
I'm not sure how to access this token in IOS. But i found a method to get attributes directly:
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/user-attributes/q/platform/ios